# How to handle blank returned JSON data from an AJAX request in AJAX

Tags: json, jquery

I have a `$.ajax` function that is calling an asp.net Webmethod.

When no data is returned I want to alert the user with a window.

This is the returned JSON string I see in FireBug:

```
{"d": "[]"}
```

The following is a snipet of the function -

```
success: function (msg) {
    var data = eval(msg.d);
    var i = 0;
    var Name;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data.length == 0) {
            alert('oops no data has been returned sorry.');
        } else {
            //do the good stuff
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: What is it always with all the space on the left side? I find left-aligned code much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `if-else` statement outside the `for` loop and the `for` loop inside the `else` branch:

```
if (data.length == 0) {
    alert('oops no data has been returned sorry.');
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //do the good stuff
    }
}
```

In your code, the `if` statement will never be executed if `data` is empty since the `for` loop body is never executed (`0 < 0` is `false`).

---

**Other issues:**

I recommend to fix your JSON generation process. If `msg.d` is supposed to contain array, then don't assign it a string. Your JSON should look like

```
{"d": []}
```

It seems like you double-encode the data somehow.

If you don't do this, I would at least use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`.

Comment: JSON.Parse seems slower than eval..However Felix that worked and thanks for all the responses!

Comment: @CoolDude: Well, you can avoid both if you create your JSON properly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function webMethodCall(){
return $.getJSON('myURL',{/*my data*/}).done(function(msg){
 if(!msg || !msg.d.length){
         alert('Emptydata!')
    }
});
};
```